# Paragraph element with images in html

Tags: html, css

i would like to create html like this :

[image]

text start with "we all grew up, reiterating to oursleves...." have 2 lines with image, and 3rd like start with left alignment

i take following elements for this ;

```
<ul class ="ariticaldiv">
        <li>
            <div>
                <img src="../Images/DefaultPhotoMale.png" alt="" />
                <span>Think About there benefits , Your Brand is your Equity</span>
                <span><span>By : xxxxx</span><span>Director Of HR</span></span>
                <span><span>Post:</span><span>March 3,2014</span></span>
                <label>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx some long text here xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

how could i do that ?

Comment: Use float:left on the image.

Comment: FWIW, `<img align="left" ...">` let you do this in HTML even before CSS was introduced. But it's not supported in HTML5, so use one of the `float` solutions below; this is actually a textbook case to of 'float`.

Answer (score 1):

If you render float the image, you'l obtain what you desire:

HTML:

```
<img src="../Images/DefaultPhotoMale.png" alt="" class='floated_image' />
```

CSS:

```
.floated_image
{
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <div>
    <p style="width: 250px">
    <img src="../Images/DefaultPhotoMale.jpg" alt="" style="float: left; width: 50px; height:    50px;margin:2px" />
    <span>Think About there benefits , Your Brand is your Equity
    By : xxxxx Director Of HR 
    Post: March 3,2014 
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx some long text here xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </span>
    </p>
```